# ANSI to UTF-8 through Java : some lines are lost

Tags: java, utf-8

I wanted to convert some files from ANSI (Arabic) to UTF-8. It works but after the new file is created, it is missing some lines (at the end). Any ideas why?

This is the code :

```
public class CustomFileConverter {

private static final char BYTE_ORDER_MARK = '\uFEFF';

public void createFile(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(input, "windows-1256"); // Arabic
    char[] data = new char[1024];
    int i = inputStreamReader.read(data);

    if(new File(outputFile).exists()){
       new File(outputFile).delete();
    }
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile,true);
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output,"UTF-8");

    String text = "";
    writer.write(BYTE_ORDER_MARK);
    while(i !=-1){
        String str = new String(data,0,i);
        text = text+str;
        i = inputStreamReader.read(data);

    }
    // System.out.print(text); It is printed Completely

    writer.write(text);
    // File lacks some final lines...

    output.close();
    input.close();      
}
```

}

Comment: What happens if you use `writer.close()` instead of `output.close()`?

Comment: I thought it probably would.  Joachim's answer explains why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When wrapping an output stream in a writer and writing to the writer, the writer may cache data before actually forwarding it to the output stream.

Since you're closing the output stream (file) before flushing the writer, there may be unwritten data which can no longer be written to the file since the output stream is closed.

Instead of closing the FileOutputStream `output`, close the writer `writer`, that will flush the contents of the writer to the file and also close both the writer itself and the wrapped FileOutputStream;